# Invoke a JSP page from a Servlet

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

Can anybody help me how can I invoke a JSP page from a Servlet (just have to invoke, no need of passing parameters).

Comment: Put your mouse above the `[servlets]` tag which you've placed on the question yourself until a black info box shows and then click therin the *info* link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `forward()` or `include()` method of the `RequestDispatcher` ([Docu](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29)):

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( "yourJspPath" )
                   .forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what 'invoke' is supposed to mean, but if we're talking about redirecting, it could be done like that:

`response.sendRedirect("your.jsp");`